# Visual Basic - Adding event support to array members

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, events, event-handling

In Visual Basic, is it possible to apply the "WithEvents" functionality to each member of an array?

For example, I create an array of objects of a custom class that contains events. Say, an array of students.

I code a procedure or property that sets values for each students' grades, and if it all grades are A, it fires an event.

Then that events' handler prints "Student xyz is a straight A student!"

How do I add event support to the array, or every member of the array individually?

The below doesn't work

```
Dim WithEvents students as Student()= New Student() {}
```

and tells me event variables cannot be typed as arrays.

This is something that wasn't covered in class but I am curious about.

Comment: You'll have to [set the event yourself manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/6yyk8z93%28v%3dvs.90%29) for each instance.

Comment: Which can then be put into a constructor. Thank you.